# Single repetition for some of the symbols in a set of characters

Tags: regex, char

I need a regular expression that matches a string containing letters and the symbols: `@`, `.` or space. But all the symbols must appear only once in the whole string.

- `^[@][.][a-z]+$` - This matches for `example@.asdf` but need something to match one `@` and one dot in the string.
- `^[a-z]+[@][a-z]+[.][a-z]+$` - This is the best result for now.

I was just wondering if I can use something like that - `^[a-z[@]{1}]$`.

Comment: ^[@][.][a-z]+$ - This matches for example@.asdf but need something to match one @ and one dot in the string.

Comment: ^[a-z]+[@][a-z]+[.][a-z]+$ - This is the best result for now. I was just wondering if I can use somethig like that - ^[a-z[@]{1}]$

Comment: are you trying to parse an email address? Because that's a lot harder than you might think... see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for details.

Comment: Your first regex (`^[@][.][a-z]+$`) won't match `example@.asdf`. That regex ensures that the string *begins* with `@.`. Also, the language you're using would be good to know, as there may be some slight differences depending on the engine. Also, do the order or relative positions of the symbols matter?

Comment: Can you update the question with: **1.** What exactly are you trying to achieve with this regex? What's the ultimate aim?, and **2.** What are some inputs you'd like to match, and some that you'd like to *not* match?

Comment: Also, do the order or relative positions of the symbols matter, or can they be mixed anywhere among letters? (I'm kind of thinking that regex might not be the best tool for the job here.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably realize that you could get away with it by writing all 6 permutations of the 3 symbols. Unfortunately, that's the best you can do with plain regular expressions because by definition the only way regexp (seen as finite state automata) can remember what happened before is through their current state, you can't have a set to store what's you've seen so far.

So you'll have to do something like this.
Say \a stands for letters (you can expand it to [a-zA-Z]) because it's bad enough like that. You can use

```
\a*([@]?\a*[.]?\a*[ ]?|[@]?\a*[ ]?\a*[.]?|[.]?\a*[@]?\a*[ ]?|[.]?\a*[ ]?\a*[@]?|[ ]?\a*[.]\a*[@]|[.]?\a*[ ]\a*[@]|)\a*
```

I threw in question marks after the charactacters, so each can appear "at most" once, if you want exactly once you just drop all the question marks.

Evidently, if you were dealing with 10 symbols and you had to write 10! permutations you'd be better off writing a function like

```
fun check_string_contains_symbols_once_at_most(str) {
 for c in str {
  if symbol_list.contains(c) {
   if symbol_seen_set.contains(c) then return false
   else if symbol_seen_set.add(c)
  }
 }
}
```